# Regular Expression to insert using replace method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
    Math.round(num1/num2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
```

I have this and if I put

```
 var num1 = 123456789;
 var num2 = 10000;
```

I get 12,346 but I do not understand how it works using replace method. Doesn't replace() method replace something, which means a character has to be deleted? But how come this function can insert comma between characters? I understand the regex one by one but do not understand how it works in total. Thanks!

Comment: `?=` and `?!` thing are called `Zero-width` assertion, which is used to represent location, it works like `^` or `$`, so it will not be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex consists of two zero-width assertions: `\B`, which matches any position that's *not* a word boundary, and `(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))`, which matches any position that's followed by `(\d{3})+(?!\d)`. So the regex matches an empty (length-zero) substring. "Removing" that substring would have no effect, so "replacing" it has the effect of just inserting the replacement-string.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the pattern can be replaced by:

```
var num = '12345678';
var res = num.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, ',');
// res -> 12,345,678
```